# does anybody know how to make an animation happen once when a player with tag player walks into a trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Makes the animation trigger and destroys the trigger after being touched by the player

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
// You should make the name TheSecretWallScript
// This is the general format for classes in C#
public class Thesecretwallscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // needed to change this.
    [SerializeField] private Animator anim;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // Disables trigger so it doesn't trigger again
        other.enabled = false;
        // Triggers animation, "AnimTrigger" should refer to the trigger you set
        // in your animators settings
        Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.SetTrigger("AnimTrigger");
    }
}
```

Comment: We need lot's more information if you want an answer to your question.

Comment: Its not working. by any chance if any body wants to chat with me on discord feel free(Cyber77#7934)

Comment: You need to code it to happen. Find some tutorials on triggers

Comment: Yes we do. Everyone knows. It's super easy.

Comment: Okay its updated what should I do because when the player walks into the trigger it nothing happens

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are destroying the trigger even before the animation trigger  happens.
Try doing the anim.getcomponent in the start method and animation.settrigger and in the next line other enabled =false.

Something like that